# Mongoose single nested model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I want to abstract away a model from my Mongoose schema:

```
AddressSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  _type: String
  first_name: String 
  last_name: String
  address_line1: String
  address_line2: String
  zip_code: String
  city: String 
  state: String
  phone_number: Number
)
AddressSchema = Schema.AddressSchema
```

and then do something like this later on:

```
ShippingChoicesRequestSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  retailer: String
  products: [ ProductSchema ]
  shipping_address: 
    ref: AddressSchema
    type: ObjectId
)
```

However, when I sent a request, it doesn't create this nested address document. I know I can do this as an array by doing something like `shipping_address: [ AddressSchema]`, but what if it's not a repeated field?

EDIT:

The request looks like:

```
{
  "retailer": "something",
  "products": [...],
  "shipping_address": {
    "_type": "address",
    "first_name": "...",
    "last_name": "...",
    "address_line1": "...",
    "address_line2": "...",
    "zip_code": "...",
    "city": "...", 
    "state": "...",
    "phone_number": ...
  }
}
```

But when I look it up in Mongo I get:

```
{
  "retailer" : "something",
  "_id" : ObjectId("526ad0a3c0cff58a54000001"),
  "products" : [
    {
      "variant_choice" : {
        "unit_price" : 3999,
        "color" : "Black",
        "size" : "M",
        "_type" : "variant_choice"
      },
      "quantity" : 1,
      "product_id" : "123456",
      "_type" : "product"
    }
  ],
  "__v" : 0
}
```

so the address doesn't get stored.

Comment: what does your request look like?

Answer (score 0):

Here we are defining the Schema:

```
AddressSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    _type: String
    first_name: String 
    last_name: String
    address_line1: String
    address_line2: String
    zip_code: String
    city: String 
    state: String
    phone_number: Number
);
```

You will also need to define the model:

```
var AddressModel = mongoose.model('Address', AddressSchema);
```

Then we can reference Address as a subdoc:

```
ShippingChoicesRequestSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    retailer: String
    products: [ ProductSchema ]
    shipping_address: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Address'}
);
```

Comment: thanks! Now I'm getting a different error though: `{ message: 'Cast to buffer failed for value "[object Object]" at path "shipping_address"'`, is there any way for me to define the entire `ShippingChoiceRequest` at once without separately defining the nested address?